# Is there a way to declare a std::array of structs in a constructor?

Tags: c++, fifo, stdarray

I have a FIFO class who's width and depth I'd like to declare when a new FIFO is instantiated.  I'd like to use a std::array as one of the elements in the FIFO record and make the FIFO a std::array of records but I haven't figured out a way to declare a std::array with a value passed into the constructor. I'd like to use std::array because it seems like a safer approach than using c style arrays but even when I try this with c style arrays, I can't figure out how to declare the arrays with values passed to the constructor. This is for an embedded app so if this is a dumb idea or there's a better way, I'd be happy to hear it.

Here's what I'd like to do but obviously the FIFORecord stuct can't see the width value passed to the constructor and I get a "non-type template argument is not a constant expression" error using the depth value to declare the array of FIFORecords in the constructor.  Thanks.

```
class FIFO
{

    struct FIFORecord
    {
        std::array<uint8_t, width> msg;
        uint32_t timestamp;
    };

public:
    FIFO(const uint32_t depth, uint32_t width, string qID)
    {
        capacity = depth;
        qWidth = width;
        head = 0;
        tail = -1;
        count = 0;
        qName = qID;
        
        std::array<FIFORecord, depth> fifoStack;
    }
```

Comment: `std::array` has its size defined at compile time. For runtime sizes, you can use `std::vector`.

Comment: Well I should have known that and I think that puts a stake in the heart of this idea.  I was hoping to use std::array since it seems to have near zero overhead.  However, using std::vector has some advantages.  in fact, it looks like my whole FIFO class can be implemented as a vector of vectors and the head, tail, count, etc. just go away.  Any idea on how to estimate the overhead associated with std::vector?

Comment: std::vector is very likely to use heap allocation, so just like C++ in general, it is isn't suitable for embedded systems.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself here is _why on earth should my embedded system declare a non-deterministic, variable size for a FIFO buffer_? Then you should ask yourself what FIFO size that is required to handle the worst case. Then you should write down that worst-case in your requirement spec: "Bus x on the product should be able to handle a maximum incoming data length of n bytes". Then adapt your program accordingly, it needs that exact FIFO size, no more, no less.

Comment: I know the size of all my FIFOs at compile time.  All the FIFOs get instantiated at the start of the program and initializing them through the FIFO class constructor seems like the appropriate way to do this. I just haven't figured out the right code to make that happen with std::array.  Hence, my question.

Comment: I'm not an embedded C++ expert by any means but I am trying to educate myself about "best practices". WRT to heap allocation, or more generally, dynamic memory allocation, my understanding is the MISRA 2008 C++ safe coding standard demands no dynamic memory allocation after initialization.  Further, my understanding is that std::array doesn't use dynamic memory.  Not that I need to be but it looks like I'm MISRA compliant here.  Interestingly, AutosarC++14 does allow std::vector and other STLs that use dynamic memory.